How does doppler cooling work?
I have trouble understanding how doppler cooling works. I understand that an atom moving towards laser sees the laser light blue-shifted and if the laser frequency is slightly below the atom's electronic transition frequency, then the atom absorbs the photon.
What I don't understand is how does this lead to the atom being cooled.
After the atom absorbs the photon, it is re-emitted after a short period of time, and the re-emission can occur in any direction. If it can occur in any direction, shouldn't the atom's mean velocity remain the same? Even the wikipedia page says (in the image caption), that "The atom re-emits a photon. As its direction is random, there is no net change in momentum over many photons."
Could someone explain how this re-emission can lead to cooling?
Also, how do the practical set-ups for doppler cooling look like? How many lasers one needs and how the lasers are positioned to cool the atom?

The emission is indeed independent of the direction and so on average does not lead to any change in momentum. However, the absorption always happens with photons traveling opposite to the atoms. So by momentum conservation, we have that $p_{new} = p_{old} - p_{ph} < p_{old}$ (where we only look at the component in the direction of travel and all quantities are positive by definition of the setup. Now the atom is excited however as you mentioned the emission on average has $p_{old} = p_{new}$ so after a full cycle of absorption/emission (on avg.) $\Delta p = - p_{ph}$

Let's consider the 1D case, in which the atom is allowed to move only along the $z$ axis, and the photons are also only absorbed/emitted in this direction. Furthermore, suppose that the atom moves with momentum $p_a$ in the positive $z$ direction and laser shoots photon along the negative $z$ direction.

Before any absorption the momentum of the atom is $p_a^{(0)}=p_a$
After the atom absorbs a single photon the momentum of the atom is $p_a - p_\gamma$.
Suppose that the emission of the photon is equally likely in the positive and the negative direction. Thus, after the emission of the photon the momentum of the atom is $p_a - 2p_\gamma$ with probability 50% and it is $p_a$ with probability 50%. Thus, the average momentum is $\bar p_a^{(1)} = 0.5 \cdot (p_a - 2p_\gamma) + 0.5\cdot p_a = p_a - p_\gamma$, which is smaller than the initial momentum.
After the second absorption and re-emission the momentum of the atom is $p_a - 4p_\gamma$ with probability 25%, $p_a - 2p_\gamma$ with probability 50% and $p_a$ with probability 25%. If we calculate the average momentum we find again that it decreased,
$
\bar p_a^{(2)} = \ldots = p_a - 2 p_\gamma
$

Doppler cooling works, because we absorb the photons from a well defined direction, which is opposite to the motion of the atom, and we reemit it in an undefined direction. Therefore, the absorption is not averaged out, but the reemission is. This lowers the average momentum.
The setup is rather simple: We just shine lasers along the six cartesian axis. However, I have never used doppler cooling by itself, but always used a so called MOT: By applying magnetic field gradients, we generate a well-defined center. The atoms are no longer allowed to stop everywhere, but are collected in the center of the MOT.
